# Critical Path, Forward and Backward Pass

Tags: project-team, critical-path

I am a bit confused in the concept of critical path. Do we need to find both the Forward and backward pass in order to find the critical path or can it be found from only one i.e. either from Forward or from Backward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need both because you need to understand early start and finish and late start and finish.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can find after you calculate both forward pass and backward pass is the float. The amount of  days a work that is not on the critical path can be moved around. this helps a lot when you have limited resources to work in your project.